# How can I separate links with spaces using regex

Tags: python, regex, hyperlink

I have a table where 2 links might be placed in 1 cell; moreover, it contains spaces which cannot be removed because the link then will not work

I tried this code

```
import re
text = 'https://unior-textile.ru/image/cache/WhatsApp Image 2020-04-16 at 14.02.35-900x900.png https://unior-textile.ru/image/cache/WhatsApp Image 2020-04-16 at 13.52.03-900x900.png'
urls = re.findall('http][s]?://(?:[a-zA-Z]|[ ]|[0-9]|[$-_@.&+]|[!*\(\),]|(?:%[0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F]))+.png', text)
print("Urls: ",urls)
```

But got this output

```
Urls:  []
```

How can I exctract these links separately to an array/list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `split` :

```py
import re

text = (
    'https://unior-textile.ru/image/cache/WhatsApp Image 2020-04-16 at 14.02.35-900x900.png '
    'https://unior-textile.ru/image/cache/WhatsApp Image 2020-04-16 at 13.52.03-900x900.png'
)

links = [
    "https://" + link.strip()
    for link in re.split("https?://", text)
    if link
]
```

Result :

```py
['https://unior-textile.ru/image/cache/WhatsApp Image 2020-04-16 at 14.02.35-900x900.png',
 'https://unior-textile.ru/image/cache/WhatsApp Image 2020-04-16 at 13.52.03-900x900.png']
```